# startActivity crashes if I do not open the activity from another path

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

So I have 2 ways an activity can be opened. One is from the activity flow of:

> Main > Tracks > Day > Topic > TrackSelect > TrackInfo

and the other is:

> Main > MySchedule > TrackInfo

If I try to get TrackInfo to open up via the second path, it crashes the app.
However, If I go from the first path, then all the way back to the main, then through the second path, it works perfectly. Is there something weird going on?

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="fayko.conference_app">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Conference-App"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity
        android:name=".mainSelection"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".topicScreen"/>
    <activity
        android:name=".myScheduleScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".trackSelection" />
    <activity android:name=".mainScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".daySelection" />
    <activity android:name=".trackInfoScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".mapChoose" />
    <activity android:name=".sponsorScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".committeeScreen" />
    <activity android:name=".welcomeScreen"></activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Code from **TrackSelect > Track Info**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(trackSelection.this,trackInfoScreen.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Code from **MySchedule > TrackInfo**:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(myScheduleScreen.this,trackInfoScreen.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I appreciate any help you guys can give me.

Comment: post the stacktrace

Comment: I second that, please post the stacktrace of the crash.  Edit:  Also please try to stick to Java naming conventions, ie. each class name should begin with a capital letter

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the issue I was having was due to some internal code. Even thought he stacktrace was saying things about socket lost for the debugger.

Comment: Ohhh... That's right, I really forget about that constraint :P https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277960/why-cant-you-accept-your-own-answer-immediately. I hope you didn't forget to close it later :P